# Can the Zoom F1 recorder and SSH6 mid/side mic record the raw Mid/Side files?

Tags: zoom

I recently purchased an zoom SSH6 that is capable of recording mid/side.  We mainly record short films,speakers and musical instruments.  Most of the time I'll likely use the stereo out the unit produces with the baked in decoding but for film or music recording I wanted to be able to control the levels in post.  I don't see an option on F1 for raw MS recording like the H5.  Does anyone know if I can get the raw MS on F1 using the SSH6?   I do see the StGun off, 30, 60, 90 settings but I'm assuming if I turn off StGun that it disables the side mic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is entirely a question for Zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to zoom and this was their response:
”Unfortunately, this is not possible using the F1. We have forwarded a request to the engineers at Zoom Corporation to add this functionality in a firmware update. We apologize for the inconvenience. “

I would encourage anyone interested in this control to reach out to them and let them know you’d like this in the f1 firmware.  If enough people ask they prioritize it higher.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same set up with the F1 & SSH-6 and was trying to find an answer to this question. After not finding any information online or from Zoom I decided to do sound tests with each setting indoors and outdoors. I found that turning StGun off does disable the side mic. The 60 or 90 settings have given good results to capture ambient room noise or fuller natural sound outdoors. The 120 or 150 settings indoors resulted in too much reverb, outdoors the 120 or 150 picked up even the slightest breeze/wind noise or ground noise while walking. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hi Laurence that’s awesome you did those field tests.  There’s supposed to be an option where you get the raw output of the mid side separate and then you can tweak the mix in post but zoom didn’t implement it on F1 (only the H-series firmware).  I also found an option in Logic to tweak the EQ using a mid mid side isolation.  That works out pretty good even without the raw output.   Thanks again for your tests!  I’m glad someone else is experimenting with this setup.